# fetching a particular column in a combobox from a ms access database using c#

Tags: c#

i have developed an application for my perfume shop. i have created a windows form in which there are two controls(a button and a combo box). i want to fetch a column (brand name) from the table (HUGO_BOSS) of my ms access database to combo box when i press that button.
 i tried the following code and it gives "System.Data.DataRowView"

```
   private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            con.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter d = new OleDbDataAdapter("select [Brand name] from HUGO_BOSS", con);
            DataSet dt = new DataSet();
            d.Fill(dt);
            comboBox3.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
            comboBox3.DisplayMember = "[Brand name]";
            con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            con.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter d = new OleDbDataAdapter("select [Brand name] as BrandName from HUGO_BOSS", con);
            DataSet dt = new DataSet();
            d.Fill(dt);
            comboBox3.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
            comboBox3.DisplayMember = "BrandName";
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it works :) but please explain what is an error and why it is ?

Comment: The problem came from the column name which had a space char in it. I created an alias for the column in the SQL query and used that alias in `DisplayMember`. Avoid creating columns with special characters in them.